# SBT `session save` - [info] No session settings defined

Tags: scala, session, sbt

I try SBT following [tutorial](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html) steps:

```
$ mkdir foo-build
$ cd foo-build
$ touch build.sbt
$ sbt
...
sbt:foo-build>
...
sbt:foo-build> compile
sbt:foo-build> run
[info] Packaging ~/Development/projects/research/scala/foo-build/target/scala-2.12/foo-build_2.12-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running example.Hello 
Hello
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2018, 12:10:41 PM
sbt:foo-build> scalaVersion
[info] 2.12.6
sbt:foo-build> session save
[info] No session settings defined.
```

following documentation, I expect

```
Save the session to build.sbt 
We can save the ad-hoc settings using session save.

sbt:foo-build> session save
[info] Reapplying settings...
build.sbt file should now contain:
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
```

but it is not with message **[info] No session settings defined.**.

Is any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow the steps you provided, you did not made changes to your build. Looks like you have forgotten [this step](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/sbt-by-example.html#Set+ThisBuild+%2F+scalaVersion+from+sbt+shell) :

```
set ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.6"
```

Hence the message `[info] No session settings defined.`.